# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

> First prove the following :$$\tag{1}\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(1+\frac{1}{\:n}\right)^n=e .$$
> If $a_{n}>0$ and $$\tag{2}\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{a_n+1}{a_n}\right) \text{and} \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}$$ both exist and are finite then they are equal.
> Then evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}\right)$$ using $(1)$ and $(2)$.

What have I done so far :

Let: $\displaystyle\mathcal{L} = \lim_{n\to \infty }\left(1+\frac{1}{\:n}\right)^n$

\begin{align}\ln(\mathcal{L}) &=\lim _{n\to \infty }n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\\\require{cancel}
&=\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}\\
&=\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}\right)\cdot \cancel{\frac{-1}{n^2}}}{\cancel{\frac{-1}{n^2}}}\\
&=\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}\:}\right)\\&=1 \implies \mathcal{L} = e\\
\end{align}
if someone can help me with proving $(2)$ or evaluate  the limit in other way will be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89d5f8WUf1Y

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily have much more than the limit itself
$$a_n=\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}\implies \log(a_n)=\frac 1 n \log(n!)-\log(n)$$ Use Stirling approximation
$$\log(a_n)=-1+\frac{\log (2 \pi  n)}{2 n}+\frac{1}{12
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)}=\frac 1 e \left(1+\frac{\log (2 \pi  n)}{2 n}+\frac{3 \log ^2(2 \pi  n)+2}{24 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Based on :

> - $1.$ $\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(1+\frac{1}{\:n}\right)^n=e$
> - $2.$ if a$_{n}$>$0$ and $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{a_n+1}{a_n}\right)$and $\lim _{n\to \infty }\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ both exist and are finite then they are equal.

we get :
\begin{align}\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}\right) =  \lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{\sqrt[n]{n^n}} = \lim _{n\to \infty }\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 \displaystyle\lim _{n\to \infty }\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}&=\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{\frac{\left(n+1\right)!}{\left(n+1\right)^{n+1}}}{\frac{n!}{n^n}}\\
&= \lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{\left(n+1\right)!}{n!}\cdot \frac{n^n}{\left(n+1\right)^{n+1}}\\
&=\lim _{n\to \infty }\frac{\left(n+1\right)\cdot n!}{n!}\cdot \frac{n^n}{\left(n+1\right)^{n+1}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n\\
&=\frac{1}{\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n}\\
&=\frac{1}{\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}\\
\end{align}

- based on $1$ the answer is $\frac{1}{e}$

Comment: What's the point of answering your own question.

Comment: @BEIRUT This [stack exchange article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) is the point of answering ones question.